# Trying to use both TCP and UDP for OPENVPN

Tags: linux, ubuntu, iptables, openvpn, vpn

I'd like to have the TCP port 1195 also open for the VPN but it just says tcp dpt:1195 instead of udp dpt:openvpn and gives an error message explicit-exit-notify can only be used with -proto udp

these are my rules:

```
ACCEPT tcp -- anywhere anywhere tcp dpt:1195 /* Allow VPN connection */

ACCEPT udp -- anywhere anywhere udp dpt:openvpn /* Allow VPN connection */
```

```bsh
cat /etc/openvpn/iptables.sh

#!/bin/bash

# Flush
iptables -t nat -F
iptables -t mangle -F
iptables -F
iptables -X

# Block All
iptables -P OUTPUT DROP
iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P FORWARD DROP

# allow Localhost
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT

# Make sure you can communicate with any DHCP server
iptables -A OUTPUT -d 255.255.255.255 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -s 255.255.255.255 -j ACCEPT

# Make sure that you can communicate within your own network
iptables -A INPUT -s 192.168.0.0/24 -d 192.168.0.0/24 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -s 192.168.0.0/24 -d 192.168.0.0/24 -j ACCEPT

# Allow established sessions to receive traffic:
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

# Allow TUN
iptables -A INPUT -i tun+ -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i tun+ -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -o tun+ -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o tun+ -j MASQUERADE
iptables -A OUTPUT -o tun+ -j ACCEPT

# allow VPN connection
iptables -I OUTPUT 1 -p tcp --destination-port 1195 -m comment --comment "Allow VPN connection" -j ACCEPT

# iptables -I OUTPUT 1 -p udp --destination-port 1194 -m comment --comment "Allow VPN connection" -j ACCEPT

# Block All
iptables -A OUTPUT -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -j DROP
iptables -A FORWARD -j DROP

# Log all dropped packages, debug only.
iptables -N logging
iptables -A INPUT -j logging
iptables -A OUTPUT -j logging
iptables -A logging -m limit --limit 2/min -j LOG --log-prefix "IPTables general: " --log-level 7
iptables -A logging -j DROP

echo "saving"

iptables-save > /etc/iptables.rules

echo "done"

#echo 'openVPN - Rules successfully applied, we start "watch" to verify IPtables in realtime (you can cancel it as usual CTRL + c)'

#sleep 3

#watch -n 0 "sudo iptables -nvL"
```

---

iptables -L

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  255.255.255.255      anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  192.168.0.0/24       192.168.0.0/24      
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
logging    all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain OUTPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:1195 /* Allow VPN connection */
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:openvpn /* Allow VPN connection */
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             255.255.255.255     
ACCEPT     all  --  192.168.0.0/24       192.168.0.0/24      
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
logging    all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain logging (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 2/min burst 5 LOG level debug prefix "IPTables general: "
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

Comment: Format your code: remove the blank lines, then put 3 back tick quotes at the start and end (on a line on their own).

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor done that for him

Comment: The OP: please just post the output of `iptables-save` - no one really wants to understand how you create the rules.

Comment: You run this script on the machine with vpn server or with vpn client?

Comment: Its all on the same machine.

Comment: Artem - I dont have anything in iptables-save its set up to run the above script from iptables.sh in rc.local at boot.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an iptables issue. But a VPN server config issue. You will need two VPN instances to accomplish this. Check [this](https://forum.netgate.com/topic/131138/use-both-tcp-and-udp-at-the-same-time-with-openvpn-server) and [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/269967/how-to-make-openvpn-to-listen-both-tcp-and-udp-ports#:%7E:text=The%20same%20openvpn%20process%20can,UDP%2C%20the%20other%20on%20TCP.)